# Get plot's symbol data

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-plot

Is any method in `Core Plot` which is called when plot is scrolled and it receives `recordIndex` parameter? My goal is to get `x` and `y` values for a symbol which appeared on the screen. I've searched in examples and documentation, but maybe I've missed something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a plot space delegate to monitor changes to the plot space. Your datasource knows what all of the data values are. You can check after each plot space change to see which data points are visible.

Comment: Using - (void)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space didChangePlotRangeForCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate, doesn't help. If I try to get xRange and yRange,     CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)space.graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    NSLog(@"1-- %@", plotSpace.xRange);
    NSLog(@"2-- %@", plotSpace.yRange);   Then I receive right values for xRange, but for yRange I get everytime same values {0-100, which actually is my y-axis range of values but not values for symbols on plot

Comment: So if I have 3 symbol drawn on plot, there is no method to get ONLY these x,y values for these 3 data points ?

Comment: The space parameter is the plot space that changed—no need to go back to the graph to get the plot space. The x- and y- ranges tell you the range of data points displayed in the plot area. Your data doesn't need to fill the range. The plot range has several methods to test values against the range (`double`, `NSDecimal`, and `NSNumber`) so it's easy to check which of your data points are visible.